# Restrict Indexation in Multistore Website

Tags: magento-1.9, index, product-reindexing

I have multistore website .When I have done translation for one store , I have found that it is done on the other stores also.
I want to make restring on indexing in the other stores .
The canonical tag indicate the correct Google version but some content like images are shown in results .
The question is how can I restrict indexing on one store 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This does not sound like an indexing issue.

If you want to display different data for different stores, you have to enter that data in the correct scope in the backend.

You should have a scope selection dropdown in the upper left of your "Edit product" screen. Find more info here: https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/configuration/scope.html

**EDIT**

First of all, you should check if your product data is translated correctly.

- check in the backend; if you select the scope of your store view, is the field content correct, for example for "description"?
- 2nd, check in the database: for example, the "description" values are stored in the table `catalog_product_entity_text`. Filter this table for the product-ID, attribute-ID for description, and store-ID of your store. Is the translation correct?
- if you want to hide a product from a certain store, do the same as above for the attribute "visibility" which is store in `catalog_product_entity_int`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but can you explain bit more

Comment: Sure, what part of the documentation linked above do you not understand?

Comment: My problem is about products that have certain behavior which means are translated that should not appear in certain stores , that is it

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand your English, but I tried a bit better how to check if your translated values get saved.

Comment: We have multiple websites(stores) linked together . We have tranlsation of porducts in one store but the problem that is appearing in the other stores. Added to that it is showing redirection when clicking on the product from another store

Comment: It's a difference if you're having "websites" or "store views". If you're using "websites", simply go to the "Edit product" screen and uncheck the box in the area "Websites". If you're using "store views", make sure that your settings for the attribute "Visibility" are correct.